# How can i decrease font size to fit a fixed height container for DOM elements within an array?

Tags: javascript, css, dom

I have a project which is pulling content from [contentful](https://www.contentful.com/) and displays news stories in a grid.

I'm trying to write a script to decrease the font size on the header tag until the text fits its parent.

I'm using a while loop in the snippet below but it only seems to decrease the size of the element once as it loops over.

How can i continue to decrease this value for every iteration ? or does anyone know a better way to achieve this result ?

I previously tried to use [FitText.js](https://github.com/davatron5000/FitText.js) only it seemed to change all the elements to the same font size.

```js
window.onload = resize_to_fit();

function resize_to_fit() {
  const CONTAINERS = document.querySelectorAll(".headline-container");
  const HEADLINETEXTS = document.getElementsByClassName('headline');

  for (i = 0; i < CONTAINERS.length; i++) {
    var headline = HEADLINETEXTS[i];
    var containerHeight = CONTAINERS[i].offsetHeight;
    var headlineHeight = HEADLINETEXTS[i].offsetHeight;
    var headlineLength = HEADLINETEXTS[i].innerHTML.length;
    var style = window.getComputedStyle(HEADLINETEXTS[i], null).getPropertyValue('font-size');
    var fontSize = parseFloat(style);
    var count = 15;

    while (headlineHeight > containerHeight && count > 0) {
      //This only seems to happen once;
      headline.style.fontSize = fontSize - 1 + "px";
      count--;
    }
  }
}
```

```js
window.onload = resize_to_fit();

function resize_to_fit() {
  const CONTAINERS = document.querySelectorAll(".headline-container");
  const HEADLINETEXTS = document.getElementsByClassName('headline');

  for (i = 0; i < CONTAINERS.length; i++) {
    var headline = HEADLINETEXTS[i];
    var containerHeight = CONTAINERS[i].offsetHeight;
    var headlineHeight = HEADLINETEXTS[i].offsetHeight;
    var headlineLength = HEADLINETEXTS[i].innerHTML.length;
    var style = window.getComputedStyle(HEADLINETEXTS[i], null).getPropertyValue('font-size');
    var fontSize = parseFloat(style);
    var count = 15;

    while (headlineHeight > containerHeight && count > 0) {
      // this only seems to happen once.
      headline.style.fontSize = fontSize - 1 + "px";
      count--;
    }
  }
}
```

```css
.headline-container {
  height: 50px;
  width: 200px;
}

h4.headline {
  font-size: 30px;
}
```

```html
<div class="headline-container">
  <a href="">
    <h4 class="headline">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Veritatis laudantium maiores culpa eaque eius fuga officia, in nihil nostrum nesciunt porro enim aut, sit quod suscipit repellat quisquam fugit corporis.</h4>
  </a>
</div>
<div class="headline-container">
  <a href="">
    <h4 class="headline">Porro non culpa saepe libero est cumque, quasi, temporibus id optio inventore ut incidunt quaerat a, maiores eaque dignissimos debitis quis. Suscipit facilis beatae tempore iste culpa, dolores dolor quo!</h4>
  </a>
</div>
<div class="headline-container">
  <a href="">
    <h4 class="headline">Ullam asperiores nobis ea, dolor voluptas, consequuntur repellat possimus deserunt quia fuga hic, optio similique sunt delectus autem voluptatem inventore tenetur nulla voluptatum ab nemo culpa. Provident dignissimos veritatis et?</h4>
  </a>
</div>
<div class="headline-container">
  <a href="">
    <h4 class="headline">Eveniet sed explicabo tempore dolorum nesciunt sapiente quasi vel quam consequuntur error, velit ullam quaerat, voluptatibus nobis voluptates, expedita vitae molestias natus laudantium architecto similique odio alias sit magnam! Fugit.</h4>
  </a>
</div>
```

Comment: Nope, it runs 15 times, but the new font size is always same. You have to do calculations inside the while loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your cached values were not changing on each iteration of the inner loop, which means that you are comparing all of the same values each time, and you would always end up with the same result.

If you don't cache values that you don't need to cache, use the values that you do need to cache (i.e. `headline` and `container` were never used in your code), and access the values directly from the inner loop, you shouldn't have a problem.

As a final note, best practices are usually fairly subjective and open to interpretation so I'm not going to tell you *how* you should do simple things, but whatever you do... please be consistent.

```js
const containers = document.getElementsByClassName('headline-container');
const headlines  = document.getElementsByClassName('headline');

for (i = 0; i < containers.length; i++) {
  const headline  = headlines [i];
  const container = containers[i];
  let count = 15;

  while (headline.offsetHeight > container.offsetHeight && count > 0) {
    const fontSize = parseInt(window.getComputedStyle(headline).fontSize);
    headline.style.fontSize = fontSize - 1 + "px";
    count--;
  }
}
```

```css
.headline-container { height: 30px; overflow: hidden; border: 1px solid } h1 { margin: 0 }
```

```html
<div class="headline-container"><h1 class="headline">Hello World</h1></div>
```